# Unlock Nexus 6P bootloader without starting phone

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock, nexus-6p

Is there a way to unlock the Nexus 6P bootloader when I am not able to start the phone anymore? I am experiencing the infamous bootloop and cannot start my phone anymore. I would like to flash a fresh image on it in the hopes that will fix my boot issue.

Thanks Simon

Comment: Only if you have already enabled OEM Unlocking in Developer Options, otherwise you cannot unlock the bootloader.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not done that and now I can't anymore.

Comment: Then to my knowledge there is no way to unlock the bootloader or flash a factory image. Sorry.

Comment: Oh man, great. I got an expensive brick now... :-(